# IBM OpenJPA NullPointerException in getResultList()

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I have spent all day trying to get native SQL to run with JPA, for a legacy migration project.  I've simplified the query to something that **should** work.

```
Query query = localEm.createNativeQuery("SELECT ID FROM TABLE");
List results = query.getResultList();
```

But I get a NPE from within the JPA code, via query.getResultList():

**NullPointerException at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:328)**

It's driving me crazy.  I've scoured the [QueryImpl source](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/openjpa/branches/2.1.x/openjpa-persistence/src/main/java/org/apache/openjpa/persistence/QueryImpl.java?view=markup).  I'm using IBM WebSphere, (WSJPA 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT and OpenJPA 2.1.1-SNAPSHOT), so the line numbers don't help, but it doesn't look like anything significant has changed in that part of the code for 2.2.0.  But I don't see anything wrong in their code.  My other JPA calls with my localEm (Entity Manager) are working fine.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What's the type and value of `micAcc`? What's the datatype of the according column? Maybe you got a mapping problem. What happens if you remove the `mic_acc` field from your query?

Comment: micAcc is a String, 'D000001546', the column is CHAR(10) in the db, and mapped as String in the mapping. Removing the WHERE clause still results in NPE in getResultList().

Comment: please disregard these first three comments, as I started the question about query.setParameter() throwing a NPE.  I removed the WHERE clause in the question, so now it's a question about getResultList throwing an NPE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it.

If I place the code in my Remote bean (the Dao), it works.
If I place the code in my Session bean (which injects the Dao), it doesn't work.

I guess the reference to the EntityManager must probably be severed at some point when returning from a Remote bean.

It was an EJB problem (or rather my poor understanding of EJB problem), however the NPEs thrown from the OpenJPA code still seems like a bug to me.